# Affection id with the base

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have 3 Entity Module, Course, Chapter
I have a course 1 belongs to module 1 and course 2 to module 2
my problem when registering course in the database, it affects me the last module in both courses

here is my code
an array that contain all the information retrieved since ajax

```
   array:4 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "id" => "itemdat-1"
    "name" => "Module 1"
    "pid" => "1"
    "type" => "Module "
    "parent" => "module_1"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "id" => "itemdat-101"
    "name" => "Module 2"
    "pid" => "1"
    "type" => "Module "
    "parent" => "module_1"
  ]
  2 => array:6 [
    "id" => "itemcour-1"
    "name" => "Cours 1"
    "pid" => "itemdat-1"
    "type" => "Cours "
    "parent" => "cours_1"
    "parentNodes" => array:1 [
      0 => array:1 [
        0 => "module_1"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  3 => array:6 [
    "id" => "itemcour-2"
    "name" => "Cours 2"
    "pid" => "itemdat-101"
    "type" => "Cours "
    "parent" => "cours_2"
    "parentNodes" => array:1 [
      0 => array:1 [
        0 => "module_1"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

In the following code you find my code
I explain how i did 
I manage the module after I add the id of the array module recupére then in the course I check if pid course equal to the id so I made a findby and I set the course in the base

```
if ($data = $request->get('moduleconfig_forms')) {
        $jsonData = $request->get('moduleconfig_forms');

        $tabpid =array();
        foreach ($jsonData as $indexs => $modules) {

            $formation = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Formation::class)->find($formationId);
            $emptyModuleConfig = 0;
            if ($modules['type'] == "module") {
                $module = new Module();
                $module->setPid($modules['id']);
                $module->setName($modules['name']);
                $module->setFormation($formation);
                $manager->persist($module);
                $manager->flush();
                array_push($tabpid, $modules['id']);
            }

            if ($modules['type'] == "Cours") {

                $id_courspid = $modules['pid'];

                if (in_array($id_courspid, $tabpid)) {

                    $cours = new Cours();
                    $cours->setName($modules['name']);
                    $cours->setPid($modules['id']);
                    $cours->setModule($module);
                    $manager->persist($cours);
                    $manager->flush();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in this code:

```
$cours->setModule($module);
```

The `$module` variable is set in the `foreach` loop and will keep the value of the second module.

One option (depending on wether or not referenced modules from courses could already be in the database) is to do this:

```
$module = $manager->getRepository(Module::class)->findOneByPid($id_courspid);
$cours->setModule($module);
```

Of course you could also simply store each `$module` object in an array, where the key is the pid, ex `$moduleEntities[$module->getPid()] = $module;` and find the correct one in the array later `$cours->setModule($moduleEntities[$id_courspid])`

Comment: thank you for your replay from what I understood i must add in
   if ($modules['type'] == "Cours") {
  $moduleRepositorys = $moduleRepository->findBy(array('pid' => $tabpid)); and i set   $cours->setModule($moduleRepositorys);

Comment: if it works, mark the question as solved and this answer as the correct one, and perhaps upvote it :)